# Installing LARCH-EcoPlanIt toolbar in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, installation

In my study I´m looking for ecological corridors and I would like to use the LARCH model for it. I have downloaded it from this side http://www.wageningenur.nl/nl/Expertises-Dienstverlening/Onderzoeksinstituten/Alterra/Faciliteiten-Producten/Software-en-modellen/LARCH.htm . Now I would like to add the tool to my ArcMap (version 10.2) document. The instruction manual already says that the tool works best in version 9.2 and 9.3 but I want to give it a try. 
To insert it into ArcMap the instruction manual says that I have to unzip it and then to install it by clicking on setup.exe and then to dubbelclick on clusdist.exe. But if I look at the unzipped file, there are no .exe files at all in it.